# Java BufferedImage type 24 bit with alpha

Tags: java, types, bufferedimage, alpha, bit

Is there a way to create 24 bit BufferedImage with alpha?
I use **BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(100,100,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)** and I didn't find proper key for 24-bit BufferedImage with alpha type in documentation.

Comment: Full color bitmaps usually use 8 bits per channel.  With 24 bits, that translates to 8 bits for red, green, and blue (but not alpha), giving the familiar 16 million or so permutations of colors.  You could probably find a specification for using 6 bit color channels that would let you squeeze RGBA into 24 bits, but you're probably much better off using a 32 bit image (8 bits each for RGB and alpha), which is widely supported.

Comment: I dont mind to use 32 bit BufferedImage. The question is how to create it. I didn't find any flags in documentation that allow to create BufferedImage that is > 8 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your question (the `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` flag) will do what you want.  With respect to your comment:

> I dont mind to use 32 bit BufferedImage. The question is how to create it. I didn't find any flags in documentation that allow to create BufferedImage that is > 8 bit.

The [documentation (link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB) uses the phrase "8-bit RGBA color components", indicating 8 bits per color channel per pixel, for a total of 4x8 bits per pixel (one for each of RGBA).